# How do I reopen MDI forms that were open during last application run?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

Is there any standard method to save and restore the state(which forms were open and where on screen), when using MDI forms?

Yes, i can save the values from MdiChildren to a file and restore them on application start. 
That is not what I am looking for.

Is there a standard way to do this?

If you have a method that is better than serializing values from MdiChildren, do post it.

Comment: It's configuration, so it can be stored, as you mentioned 1) serialized in files 2) in database 3) in registry. Choose the way that serves you best of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching quite a bit, here is the conclusion:

No, there is no standard solution.

Writing the parts of data you need to restore the window and its state is really easy.
Just serialize and write to a file on the `Closed` event on the MdiParent.
(Events like `Application.Exit` are too late to serialize. Forms are already closed).

Read it back, populate whatever you want and then `Show` the the child forms on `Load` of the MdiParent.

*I will accept this as the answer, cause it is what I used and I don't like leaving around unanswered questions.*